# What's the deal with chests?

Tags: candy-box

I've been playing Candy Box today and I found a chest at the end of one the quests! It had a wonderful pair of boots and lots of candies inside. Now I want to find more chests. The problem is, I haven't found one since. So are chests random or is there a specific way to trigger them? Can they only be found during questing? Basically, tell me everything you know about chests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're random.  In the peaceful forest, each tree has a base 1/100 chance to be a chest instead.  Each chest you find reduces the chance to 1/150, 1/200, 1/250, etc.  On Mount Goblin the base chance is 1/50, which decreases in the same way.  The basic chest always drops a key to the lollipop farm if you don't have it, and has a 1/3 chance to drop each of the boots, map to swamp, and map to hut, as well as 300 + d500 candies.

Answer (score 2):

They are random in the first two levels. However, in the Castle Keep level, the 2nd to last room has a random number of chests with a sizeable amount of candies inside. I found that when starting, replaying Peaceful forrest and finding the occasional chest of candies really helped.